# Two usercontrols per page in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible to have two controls on one page side-by-side in Silverlight?  It seems very restrictive to have just one user control on just one page.

I am new to silverlight.  But each page seems to have this "UserControl x:Class..." at the top of the main page XAML.  So what if you want to have an app where there are two side-by-side that influences each other?

OK, it is not in the App, it is in the page.xaml.  So I guess to explain further let me ask this.  Is it possible to have two pages in onw app?

I am trying to have two prebuilt controls (a visi control and a vectorlight tree control) on the same page.  The format of the app looks something like this:

[image]

So I want a tree view on the left side and the visi control on the right side of one app.  Is this possible?

The tree view example has this user control code

```
<UserControl x:Class="TreeViewProgrammatic.Page"

xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"

xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

xmlns:liquidTreeView="clr-namespace:Liquid;assembly=Liquid.TreeView"

Width="400" Height="300">
```

and the other control has a user control code like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LiveUpdate.Page"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
Width="500" Height="340">
```

is there a way of having the two on one page.xaml?

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem - for example, have you tried using `Grid` to layout items, other controls? In fact, are you talking about _within_ the app or _within_ the hosting page?

Comment: Can it be done within the hosting page?  Can I have two controls in one hosting page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll have at interpretting your requirements.  You have two derivatives of `UserControl` containing in part some third party controls (actually irrelevant to the requirement) and some of your own code to make these controls do things that you want them to.

Now you'd like to have them both visible to the user side by side, they interact with one another so its desirable that they run in same Silverlight app.

You've called both of them "Page" but then placed them in their own namespace (probably because you've actually created two probjects).   So first step is to create a new silverlight application and put them both in this same project, lets call the project "Xarzu1", lets also rename your `UserControl` derivatives to `TreeViewProgrammatic` and `LiveUpdate` so we don't have two controls with the useless name of "Page".

Now edit the MainPage.xaml so that it looks like this:-

```
<UserControl x:Class="Xarzu1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xarzu1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="800">
     <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:TreeViewProgrammatic />
        <local:LiveUpdate />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now both your controls are display side by side.

Comment: so what you are saying is this.  There is a main page and then the other xamls are sub pages?  would TreeViewProgrammatic and  LiveUpdate have their own XAML pages?

Comment: the IDE does not like "local".  When I type in "<local...", the editor complains that it is not defined.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Thinking I understand what you mean, the `Page` *is* a control itself (the root control) and can contain controls; initially it should contain a `Grid` which spans the size of the `Page`, this means you can place a control in the `Grid` to consume all space on the `Page`. We can, though, define `Column`s and `Row`s within the `Grid`, so, consider this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="I'm on the left side!" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="I'm on the right side!" />
</Grid>
```

The same applies to custom `UserControl` items - *that itself* is the root control and those added to it are children, this is what makes up a composite control.

Comment: Shouldn't the first control on a silverlight page be a UserControl?

Comment: You mean the root control, as in the child-control host? Yes. Place this within the body of the control/page to check the results.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error while instanciating 2 instances of a user control? As far as I know it should be possible to have multiple user controls in a silverlight page. Can you post some code about what you are trying to do?

Comment: That is not it.  I want to have two different controls on one page.  Is this possible?